# Referencing Figures in Latex

Tags: reference, latex, figures

I am currently writing my thesis in **greek** and whenever I try to reference a figure I get the following in my text:

> [;;]

This is the code I wrote:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\label{ fig:image1}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image1}
\caption{Απεικόνιση τρόπου κληρονομικότητας}
\end{figure}
```

And I call the ref by writing: `{\ref{fig:{image1}}`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a simple rule in latex `\caption` should always come before `\label` [1]. So the code you write becomes:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{image1}
\caption{Απεικόνιση τρόπου κληρονομικότητας}
\label{fig:image1}
\end{figure}
```

Also, you were referring to the image incorrectly.
and you can refer it using `\ref{fig:image1}` to get the correct reference.

This will work well, as the key you use for `\label` is the key you use for `\ref`.

References
[1] https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption